# Trying to organize toJson data in Laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel

I'm trying to create a website using Laravel. I have a 'annonces' table in my database and I want to show all of it's content into my website.

Here is my Controller function

```
public function annonceAffiche() {
    $data = Annonce::all()->toJson();
    return $data;
}
```

And my Annonce class

```
    class Annonce extends Model
{
    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

However, it only shows a string of all the data, I can't organize it. Something like that :

```
[{"user_id":32,"created_at":"2020-04-16T18:13:13.000000Z","updated_at":"2020-04-16T18:13:13.000000Z","description":"A description","titre":"A title","prix":1}]
```

What can I do ?

Comment: What do you mean, organize it? If you want your results in a certain order, you can add `orderBy` to your `Annonce::all()` call

Comment: @aynber I mean that I only want to show 'title', 'description' and 'price' into my website

Comment: You can add a `select()` statement, and change `all()` to `get()`. You can see all of the functions you can use at https://laravel.com/docs/master/queries

Comment: @aynber This works perfectly, thanks ! One last thing, how can I delete the [{...}] surrounding my data ?

Comment: If you're getting all the results, you can't, as that denotes an array of items. Removing it will invalidate your json. If you want just 1 result and remove the brackets, then you can use `first()` to get the very first result.

Comment: @aynber Okay, thank you !

Answer (score 0):

From the docs [here:](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json)

Set the `$appends` and add a getter for the attribute:

```
class Annonce extends Model {
    protected $appends = ['user'];

    public function getUser() {
         return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```